asp.net core link from admin area to non-area not working when there is culture in routing
I have asp.net core app which has admin, Identity and public (non-area)
and I have also implemented culture in routes as first parameter
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "areas",
      pattern: "{culture:length(2)}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{culture:length(2)}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

in areas/admin/views/Home/index.cshtml I have below links notice asp-area attributes
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy" asp-area="" >Public</a>
@Html.RouteLink("Public via RouterLink", "Default",new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" }) 
@Html.ActionLink("Public via ActionLink", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)

above links are getting rendered as below
<a href="/en/Admin/Home/About">About</a>
<a href="">Public</a>
<a href="">Public via RouterLink</a> 
<a href="">Public via ActionLink</a>

In all the links where I have specified area = "" the html <a> tag is rendered with empty href
links from non-area to area are working fine
also link from one area to abother also working fine
but only from area to non-area having this issue
this is happening after I have implemented culture based routing shown in first code block above

I got the solution that is to specify culture attribute explicitly
@Html.ActionLink("Public via ActionLink", "Index", "Home", new { area = "", culture="en" }, null)

